# Listen to unknown/all events in Angular2

Tags: angular, events, event-handling, dom-events

## Problem

Currently I don't know what event occurs on a certain user action and want to figure this out by executing the action and see what happens.

I also don't know if it's an event on a special element (on my `<input>`) or a global (keyboard?) event.

## Question

How can I figure out which event's occur on my action?

## Desirable Approaches

Some angular event binding to all events, like `<input (*)=log($event)>` would be nice.

Some developer tools trick to show occurring events would also be nice.

Comment: specifically my problem is tracking the autocomplete/hanzi selection of Chinese keyboards on an iOS keyboard. But I'd prefer a general answer here :)

Answer (score -1):

Not sure exactly what you're after perhaps something like this :-

```
@HostListener('document:keydown', ['$event'])
    public doSomething(e) {
        console.log("Event", e);
    }
```

This will fire the event for any key down on the whole document. You could remove the event specification and get all events. If you want to use `Observables` you could use `fromEvent()` - docs about that here [Rxjs from even docs.](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/fromevent.md)